# Local time in RCS is set to GMT not PST

Tags: archive, timezone

I fear this question will be booted as off-topic, but since there appears to be no RCS forum, I'll try it anyway.     I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and use RCS.       According to `System-settings -> Date & Time` I'm on Pacific time.    However, when I archives files using the `ci` command which is part of RCS, and the -zLT flag, the time stamp is GMT.    Presumably, `ci` is getting this from somewhere on my system?

(Edited 9/23)   I should have mentioned originally that I didn't have this problem till moving to 14.04.   As a clue, before that I used `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change time zones when I traveled.    Now, for some reason this no longer works, and I have to use `timedatectl set-time` to accomplish the same thing.   I suspect that that may be what's causing the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables?  I'd start looking here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rcS.5.html.

UNIX and its children use UTC as the system time and then set the offset from that through a $TIMEZONE, $TZ or similar variable.

Comment: That won't work because only one application (RCS) is showing the wrong time (GMT).

Comment: I agree.  I've also cheed for the environment variables suggested by @C. Knox but can't find anything similar.     Please note the expanded version of the question, which may contain a clue.

Comment: You make my point.  The behavior indicates that that application (RCS) probably has an environment variable set.  Do something to dump the environment variables -- maybe a "set" statement in the .rc script to see what the environment is.